# After updating to bokeh 1.2 I am experiencing several problems running my bokeh app with gridplot

Tags: python, bokeh

I have just upgraded to bokeh 1.2 and my bokeh app stopped working giving me the following error and showing just a blank page:

```
05:04 [WARNING] W-1000 (MISSING_RENDERERS): Plot has no renderers: Figure(id='1177', ...)
05:04 [WARNING] W-1005 (FIXED_SIZING_MODE): 'fixed' sizing mode requires width and height to be set: Column(id='1209', ...)
05:04 [WARNING] W-1005 (FIXED_SIZING_MODE): 'fixed' sizing mode requires width and height to be set: Column(id='1255', ...)
05:04 [WARNING] W-1005 (FIXED_SIZING_MODE): 'fixed' sizing mode requires width and height to be set: WidgetBox(id='1174', ...)
05:04 [WARNING] W-1005 (FIXED_SIZING_MODE): 'fixed' sizing mode requires width and height to be set: WidgetBox(id='1175', ...)
05:04 [WARNING] W-1005 (FIXED_SIZING_MODE): 'fixed' sizing mode requires width and height to be set: WidgetBox(id='1176', ...)
```

Does anyone has any clue of why it is doing that? everything works fine with bokeh 1.0.4

I have tried changing the sizing mode and to specify width and height but it displays a blank page if I don't choose 'fixed' or it just keeps giving error messages with plot_width and plot_height among the gridplot attributes.

Also, the first warning indicates a plot with a missing renderer, and it is referred to an empty figure I've created to have just a blank space of specific size in the gridplot. Any suggestion to fix that as well?

Below you can see the portion of the code I'm using:

```py
widget_highlight_select = widgetbox([highlight_select])

widget_cd_select_button = widgetbox([rendering_button]+[customer_select]+[debtor_select])

widget_degree_select = widgetbox([degree_select])

empty = figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=100) #just to create space between widgets
empty.outline_line_color = None

plot.renderers.append(graph)

patterns_series = column([fig, ts])

#layout
l = gridplot([[widget_highlight_select, widget_degree_select, empty, widget_cd_select_button, None,spinner], [plot, patterns_series]], sizing_mode='fixed') #, merge_tools=False)
```

Comment: Can you write a complete example in your question please?

Comment: The errors suggest that the API changed between version 1.0.4 and 1.2. For instance, as the errors suggests, the width and height attribute of layout objects must be explicitly set when the sizing mode is set to "fixed": https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/layouts.html#bokeh.models.layouts.LayoutDOM.sizing_mode

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already tried to explicitly fix width and height of the gridplot without success, I'll further explore the problem today and I'll try to manage to post a meaningful portion of code

Answer (score 4):

Note that some warnings are not necessarily 'problems' that need fixing. I get the missing renderers a lot in bokeh apps I make because I like to start with empty plots and empty sources and fill them based on inputs.

In such cases you can silence these warnings like this:

```
from bokeh.core.validation import silence
from bokeh.core.validation.warnings import EMPTY_LAYOUT, MISSING_RENDERERS
silence(EMPTY_LAYOUT, True)
silence(MISSING_RENDERERS, True)
```

However I would only add these when the code is all done or you may miss warnings that you'd actually want to fix when developing.

For the 'fixed_size' warning I will suggest alternatives instead of an answer:

You can use a Spacer object with a given width and height

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html

Before the Spacer was implemented you could use empty Div widgets for spacing elements.

Comment: Thanks for replying and for the useful advice. The main problem is about the 'fixed_size' I guess, and even trying to use fixed size for layout width and height the app doesn't work, showing a blank page. It seems to be running, but nothing shows up, which is very weird since everything was fine before the update..

Comment: Yeah with bokeh v2.3 I get FIXED_SIZING_MODE when calling gridplot (even when both plot_width and plot_height are both provided - and all nested child widgets have both width and height attributes).